# One Interface of a Dual NIC not detected in ip addr or DPDK-VPP

Tags: debian, network-interface

Recently, I installed VPP on Debian. I have a Intel x520-DA2 dual 10Gbps NIC on a PCI-E port attached to a Supermicro chassis.

After installing on Debian (This was also the case on Ubuntu 20.04), I see both of the interfaces on lshw, but not in the VPP show hardware brief command.

Lshw output:

```
sudo lshw -class network -businfo
Bus info          Device  Class          Description
====================================================
pci@0000:02:00.0          network        82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:02:00.1          network        82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection
pci@0000:06:00.0          network        Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE
pci@0000:06:00.1          network        Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE
pci@0000:07:00.0  eno3    network        Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE
pci@0000:07:00.1          network        Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE
```

VPP command:

```
vpp# show hardware brief
              Name                Idx   Link  Hardware
GigabitEthernet0/0                 2    down  GigabitEthernet0/0
  Link speed: unknown
  RX Queues:
    queue thread         mode      
    0     main (0)       polling   
    1     main (0)       polling   
  TX Queues:
    TX Hash: [name: hash-eth-l34 priority: 50 description: Hash ethernet L34 headers]
    queue shared thread(s)      
    0     no     0
GigabitEthernet0/1                 3    down  GigabitEthernet0/1
  Link speed: unknown
  RX Queues:
    queue thread         mode      
    0     main (0)       polling   
    1     main (0)       polling   
  TX Queues:
    TX Hash: [name: hash-eth-l34 priority: 50 description: Hash ethernet L34 headers]
    queue shared thread(s)      
    0     no     0
TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1            1    down  TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1
  Link speed: unknown
  RX Queues:
    queue thread         mode      
    0     main (0)       polling   
    1     main (0)       polling   
  TX Queues:
    TX Hash: [name: hash-eth-l34 priority: 50 description: Hash ethernet L34 headers]
    queue shared thread(s)      
    0     no     0
```

And the interfaces I associated to VPP:

```
#/etc/vpp/startup.conf
dpdk {
        dev 0000:06:00.0 {
                num-rx-queues 2
                name GigabitEthernet0/0
        }
        dev 0000:06:00.1 {
                num-rx-queues 2
                name GigabitEthernet0/1
        }
        dev 0000:02:00.0 {
                num-rx-queues 2
                name TenGigabitEthernet1/0/0
        }
        dev 0000:02:00.1 {
                num-rx-queues 2
                name TenGigabitEthernet1/0/1
        }
}
```

Notice that there are four set, but only three showing up.

I should note that, even before VPP's driver was bound to these interfaces, the interface didn't show up in the `ip addr show` command.

I want to see if that port is possibly defective or something, because the driver doesn't seem to be the problem. What is the best set of diagnostics to run on this?

UPDATE: Ok, so on boot, I found this:

```
[    0.497278] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497280] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497283] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497285] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497288] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 7: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497289] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 7: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497292] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 10: no space for [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497294] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 10: failed to assign [mem size 0x00100000 64bit]
[    0.497465] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x80000000-0x8007ffff 64bit]
[    0.497474] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x80080000-0x800fffff 64bit]
[    0.497483] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0x80100000-0x80103fff 64bit]
[    0.497491] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 7: assigned [mem 0x80104000-0x80203fff 64bit]
[    0.497496] pci 0000:02:00.0: BAR 10: assigned [mem 0x80204000-0x80303fff 64bit]
[    0.497501] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0x80304000-0x80307fff 64bit]
[    0.497509] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 7: assigned [mem 0x80308000-0x80407fff 64bit]
[    0.497514] pci 0000:02:00.1: BAR 10: assigned [mem 0x80408000-0x80507fff 64bit]
[    1.214916] pci 0000:02:00.0: Adding to iommu group 16
[    1.214935] pci 0000:02:00.1: Adding to iommu group 17
[    1.585446] ixgbe 0000:02:00.0: Adapter removed
[   34.725911] ixgbe 0000:02:00.0 0000:02:00.0 (uninitialized): eeprom read at offset 40 failed
[   34.726171] ixgbe 0000:02:00.0 0000:02:00.0 (uninitialized): eeprom read at offset 39 failed
[   34.726438] ixgbe 0000:02:00.0: HW Init failed: -15
```

It appears that the secondary interface does not raise these errors (As we already know, since it's showing up properly).

Maybe this is a kernel-related issue? I just don't know why it'd be one of two. I'd expect either it worked completely or didn't work at all.

Finally, here is the output of `lspci -vvv`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Oracle/SUN Ethernet Server Adapter X520-2
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr+ Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    IOMMU group: 16
    Region 0: Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=512K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at d020 [disabled] [size=32]
    Region 4: Memory at 80100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D3 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=64 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=4 offset=00002000
    Capabilities: [a0] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 512 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 0.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 5GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x4 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 260ms to 900ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [e0] Vital Product Data
        Product Name: Sun Dual 10GbE SFP+ PCIe LP
        Read-only fields:
            [PN] Part number: 7051223
            [EC] Engineering changes: E70856-010
            [SN] Serial number: 159048B+141090E2BA543F18
            [V1] Vendor specific: Intel Corporation
            [V2] Vendor specific: 8086
            [V3] Vendor specific: 10FB
            [V4] Vendor specific: 108E
            [V5] Vendor specific: 7B11
            [V6] Vendor specific: 11.5W
            [V7] Vendor specific: 1.0W
            [V8] Vendor specific: N/C
            [RV] Reserved: checksum good, 0 byte(s) reserved
        Read/write fields:
            [YA] Asset tag: N/A
        End
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap+ ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap+ ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Device Serial Number 90-e2-ba-ff-ff-54-3f-18
    Capabilities: [150 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
        IOVCap: Migration-, Interrupt Message Number: 000
        IOVCtl: Enable- Migration- Interrupt- MSE- ARIHierarchy+
        IOVSta: Migration-
        Initial VFs: 64, Total VFs: 64, Number of VFs: 0, Function Dependency Link: 00
        VF offset: 128, stride: 2, Device ID: 10ed
        Supported Page Size: 00000553, System Page Size: 00000001
        Region 0: Memory at 0000000080104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
        Region 3: Memory at 0000000080204000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
        VF Migration: offset: 00000000, BIR: 0
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: ixgbe
```